# Build on target with Eclipse C/C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, build

I've been using Netbeans nicely for a while to build C/C++ projects directlyon target. This removes cross-compiling problems from host and is efficient as long asyour target is powerful enough.

Until I found out NB does not support to recursively copy sources of relative projects. I don't think I'll ever find a solution for that.

So I'm considering switching to another IDE but I didn't find a way to build on target from Eclipse on host. Has anyone done that ?